# The null value is being validated. Laravel

Tags: laravel, validation

I have a form with dynamically added / removed inputs, however if I add input and don't enter anything, the null value is written to the database, the validator does not catch null. Googling did not find a similar question, on the contrary, everyone was interested in how to pass null through the validator. Maybe I didn't google it well.

[image: DB]

```
$request->validate([
    'properties' => 'required|min:1',
]);
```

Properties fiel:

```
<div class="input-group row">
                  <label for="category_id" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Product properties: </label>
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-lg-12">
                          <div id="inputFormRow">
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                              @isset($product)
                                @foreach($product->properties as $prod)
                                    <input type="text" name="properties[][key]" value="{{ $prod['key'] ?? '' }}" class="form-control m-input editinp-key" placeholder="Key" autocomplete="off">
                                    <input type="text" name="properties[][value]" value="{{ $prod['value'] ?? '' }}" class="form-control m-input ml-3 editinp-value" placeholder="Value" autocomplete="off">
                                    <div class="input-group-append ml-3">
                                        <button id="removeRow" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
                                    </div>
                                @endforeach
                              @endisset
                                @if(Session::has('properties'))
                                  @foreach(Session::get('properties') as $prop)
                                    <input type="text" name="properties[][key]" value="{{ $prop['key'] ?? '' }}" class="form-control m-input" placeholder="Key" autocomplete="off">
                                    <input type="text" name="properties[][value]" value="{{ $prop['value'] ?? '' }}" class="form-control m-input ml-3" placeholder="Value" autocomplete="off">
                                  <div class="input-group-append ml-3">
                                      <button id="removeRow" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
                                  </div>
                                  @endforeach
                                @endif
                              </div>
                          </div>

                          <div id="newRow"></div>
                          <button id="addRow" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Add</button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#addRow").click(function () {
        var html = '';
        html += '<div id="inputFormRow">';
        html += '<div class="input-group mb-3">';
        html += '<input type="text" name="properties[][key]" class="form-control m-input ml-3" placeholder="Key" autocomplete="off">';
        html += '<input type="text" name="properties[][value]" class="form-control m-input ml-3" placeholder="Value" autocomplete="off">';
        html += '<div class="input-group-append ml-3">';
        html += '<button id="removeRow" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</div>';
        
        $('#newRow').append(html);
    });

  // remove row
  $('#removeRow').on('click', function () {
      $(this).closest('#inputFormRow').remove();
  });
```

Comment: Is the image your request body? If not, please also include it.

Comment: @vcxbgfx try to check you are getting correct values for relevant keys using `dd($request)` before validating it

Comment: @jrcamatog, Thanks for the answer! The image is what goes into the database if the input is empty.I added html to my question, it's a little confusing, but I hope you can understand.

Comment: @Nikhil Radadiya, Thanks for the answer! I'll try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you pass an array of objects with `key` and `value` keys, you can validate your request like this:

```php
$request->validate([
   'properties' => 'required|min:1',
   'properties.*.key' => 'required',
   'properties.*.value' => 'required',
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use Validator ?

```
    $data = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'properties' => ['present', 'string', 'min:1'],
    ]);
    if ($data->fails()) {
        $error_msg = "Validation failed, please reload the page";
        return Response::json($data->errors());
    }
```

From further comments I realized what it is you are trying to do:
It is very similar to what i did here:
page.blade.php:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
    @if ($errors->any())
        <tbody id="dynamic_field-1">
            @php $name_count = 1 @endphp
            @foreach (old('name') as $name)
                @if($name_count == 1)
                    <tr id="{{$name_count}}">
                        <td style="width: 90%; padding: 0px; position: relative;"><input style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 100%; border: none; border-radius: 0px;" type="text"    name="name[]"   value="{{old('name.'.($name_count-1))}}"  class="form-control  @error('name.'.($name_count-1)) is-invalid @enderror" maxlength="240"/></td>
                        <td style="width: 10%;"><button type="button" name="add"      id="add-1"                                class="btn btn-success">{{ __('Add More') }}</button></td>
                    </tr>
                @else
                    <tr id="row{{$i}}">
                        <td style="width: 90%; padding: 0px; position: relative;"><input style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 100%; border: none; border-radius: 0px;" type="text"    name="name[]"   value="{{old('name.'.($name_count-1))}}"  class="form-control  @error('name.'.($name_count-1)) is-invalid @enderror" maxlength="240"/></td>
                        <td style="width: 10%;"><button type="button" name="remove"   id="{{$i}}"                               class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td>
                    </tr>
                @endif
                @php $i += 1 @endphp
                @php $name_count += 1 @endphp
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    
    @else
        <tbody id="dynamic_field-1">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 90%; padding: 0px; position: relative;"><input style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 100%; border: none; border-radius: 0px;" type="text"    name="name[]"  class="form-control" maxlength="240"/></td>
                <td style="width: 10%;"><button type="button"   name="add"      class="btn btn-success"  id="add-1" >{{ __('Add More') }}</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    @endif
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){         
            var i = {{$i ? $i+=1 : '1'}};
            $('#add-1').click(function(){
                i++;
                $('#dynamic_field-1').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td style="width: 90%; padding: 0px; position: relative;"><input style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 100%; border: none; border-radius: 0px;" type="text"    name="name[]"  class="form-control" maxlength="240"/></td><td style="width: 10%;"><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td>  </tr> ');
            });
            $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
                var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
                $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
            });
        });
```

And Controller:

```
foreach($request->input('name') as $key => $value) {
            $rules["name.{$key}"] = array('string', 'max:255');
        }
        $data = Validator::make($request->all(),   $rules);
        if ($data->fails()) {
            return redirect()
                ->back()
                ->withErrors($data)
                ->withInput($request->input());
        }else{...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Isn't that the same as using the regular $request->validate()?

Comment: It's similar to a point. This way you can create your specific validation Rules and [errors](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#specifying-a-custom-message-for-a-given-attribute) when those validation rules fail as well as many [other](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-required-if) things  As far as I know

Answer (score 0):

Your description isn't clear enough to understand. For validation you may use `required|min:1|not_in:null` for getting the validation error

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What exactly did you not understand? I have product properties, because it is not known in advance how many there will be, I dynamically form new fields using jQuery. These fields are then translated into json and loaded into the DB, if I add a new field for the product property and do not enter anything there, null will be loaded into the DB, this is exactly what needs to be prevented.

Answer (score 0):

The validation should be like this:

```
$request->validate([
    'properties' => 'required|integer|min:1',
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Integer is not suitable because this input is for product properties, it can also contain text.

Comment: Use string then instead of integer and hopefully you will be good to go. Also you can't use min:1 when using string, so remove that. It should look like this 'required|string' now.